# Functions like std::stoi for unsigned and shorter types using __gnu_cxx::__stoa

Tags: c++, c++11

C++11 introduced the new standard library function `std::stoi`, unfortunately there is no equivalent function to convert an unsigned number inside an std::string to its numeric value. Moreover, there is no direct way to convert a string to a signed/unsigned `short` and `char`.

The standard library from GNU uses the function `__gnu_cxx::__stoa` to implement `std::stoi`. Although not portable, this can be used to implement these functions:

```
namespace gnu_np {

inline int
stoi(const string& __str, size_t* __idx = 0, int __base = 10)
{ return __gnu_cxx::__stoa<long, int>(&std::strtol, "stoi", __str.c_str(),
                  __idx, __base); }

inline short
stos(const string& __str, size_t* __idx = 0, int __base = 10)
{ return __gnu_cxx::__stoa<long, short>(&std::strtol, "stos", __str.c_str(),
                  __idx, __base); }

inline char
stoc(const string& __str, size_t* __idx = 0, int __base = 10)
{ return __gnu_cxx::__stoa<long, char>(&std::strtol, "stoc", __str.c_str(),
                  __idx, __base); }

inline unsigned
stou(const string& __str, size_t* __idx = 0, int __base = 10)
{ return __gnu_cxx::__stoa<unsigned long, unsigned>(&std::strtoul, "stou", __str.c_str(),
                  __idx, __base); }

inline unsigned short
stous(const string& __str, size_t* __idx = 0, int __base = 10)
{ return __gnu_cxx::__stoa<unsigned long, unsigned short>(&std::strtoul, "stous", __str.c_str(),
                  __idx, __base); }

inline unsigned char
stouc(const string& __str, size_t* __idx = 0, int __base = 10)
{ return __gnu_cxx::__stoa<unsigned long, unsigned char>(&std::strtoul, "stouc", __str.c_str(),
                  __idx, __base); }

} // namespace gnu_np
```

Besides not being portable, it seems to work.

Do you see any reason why one or more of these functions should not work?

There is a simpler portable way to implement these functions?

Should we expect `__gnu_cxx::__stoa` remain stable in future glibc versions?

Comment: Another possibility if `sizeof (long) > sizeof (int)` is to use `std::stoul()` and then narrow to `unsigned int`, else `std::stoull()` if `sizeof (long long) > sizeof (int)`.  Only where `long long` and `int` are the same size will there be no implementation.  That excludes fewer platforms than depending on GNU compilers.  If using GCC, then it might be simpler to upgrade to get C++17 support, then use `std::from_chars()`...

Comment: @TobySpeight unfortunately I'm stuck on C++14 but I will certainly reimplement the functions with std::from_chars() as soon as our platform will move to a newer GCC version